# Change Hive table properties during select

Tags: database, hive, hiveql

I have this table that gets updated everytime a "select *" statement is run.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TABLE_EXAMPLE (
  id string
 ) 
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0001' 
 LOCATION "/locationpath/files/";
```

It reads all files that are in this path and adds them to the table.
If you start a "select *" it reads all new files and puts all information into the table. 
The idea is that, I do an select regularly and want to check if there are new files in the directory.

Problem: It doesnt update the tableproperties, specifically the "transient_lastDdlTime", the date of last change, when new data has been appended.

I need the date to change when there are new files in the directory, and therefore new data in the table when I "select *". (So I know if the table has been changed, to process it further)

Is this possible?

Greetings Oli

Comment: How do you append the data in this table? using load, insert/select ?

Comment: Thats the thing: By doing a "select * from TABLE_EXAMPLE" it adds all the new data from new files.